# Eclipse, PyDev, and Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have installed Eclipse, pyDev, and Kivy and setup my first project with a main.py file using the instructions found here:

http://www.ocularsoftware.com/2012/11/how-to-use-pydev-to-develop-and-run-kivy-applications-on-windows/

But I'm now stuck on how to create a Hello World Android app and install it on my Android emulator.

Do I need to import any part of the Android SDK?  Am I missing anything?  I don't even know what to put in my main.py except

print("Hello, World!")

EDIT: Ok I figured out how to get it to run in a test window, but I still can't get it to run in an Android virtual device.

Here is the new code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    TestApp().run()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial that you linked to does not have anything to do with Android.

The title is:

> How to use PyDev to develop and run Kivy Applications (on Windows)

note the *(on windows)* part.

So that I don't think is going to get you anywhere.

It is possible to write python apps for android. See here:
https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/

and here:
http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

I don't think kivy is going to work on sl4a though. I do believe that they have some support for GUI applications, but it is not nearly as thorough as the java SDK.

Comment: good point...I had assumed the (on Windows) part was referring to setting up Kivy on Windows...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Running the kivy apps on the android virtual machine is not supported. You need to use a actual device. for details look [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html).

The easiest way for now on windows is to::

1. Download the [pre-built VM](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B1WO07-OL50_bTR0SElrLTZGWEU)(ubuntu 12.10 warning 930+MB), it's a virtualbox disk
2. Create a new VirtualBox VM that uses this disk
3. Start the vm and follow the instructions mentioned on the Readme on the desktop of the VM.

You should have a apk ready shortly.